# How to bind JLabel with JCheckBox so when we unselect the checkbox both components are removed?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel, jcheckbox

I have a requirement in java swing. I have two checkBox (C++ and Java).

When we click on C++ on the right-side I want to create one `JLabel` with two `JCheckBox` controls.

Then when I deselect the checkBox then the components to their right-side should be removed.

[image]

```
public class CheckBoxWithJLabel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          JFrame f= new JFrame("CheckBox Example");   
          JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
          leftPanel.setBounds(40,80,200,200);  
          JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
          rightPanel.setBounds(280, 80, 100, 30);
          
          final ActionListener checkBoxActionListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    JCheckBox checkBoxType = (JCheckBox) actionEvent.getSource();
                    if (checkBoxType.isSelected()) {
                        System.out.println();
                         final JLabel label = new JLabel("Sonu");
                            label.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 30);
                            label.setText(checkBoxType.getText());
                            rightPanel.add(label);
                            f.add(rightPanel);
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Unchecked");
                    }
                }
            };
          
            JCheckBox checkbox1 = new JCheckBox("C++");    
            checkbox1.setBounds(150,100, 50,50);    
            JCheckBox checkbox2 = new JCheckBox("Java");    
            checkbox2.setBounds(150,150, 50,50);    
            leftPanel.add(checkbox1);
            leftPanel.add(checkbox2);
            checkbox1.addActionListener(checkBoxActionListener);
            checkbox2.addActionListener(checkBoxActionListener);
            f.add(leftPanel); 

            f.setSize(400,400);    
            f.setLayout(null);    
            f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: 1) `setLayout(null);` Instead use layouts. 2) Could you explain a bit more about the pairs of checkboxes on the right? What do they indicate? Is there a situation where the 2nd might be selected but the first not selected? Is it that only ever one that should be selected? I think you might be going down the wrong path here, but both to be sure & to provide good advice, I need to understand this GUI.

Comment: In left side there are two check box is there.C++ and Java.when we clicked on C++ then on right side one label will create whose name is "Language > C++" along with in the below of the label two checkbox should come. Then when we deselect the C++ check box then right side content should be removed

Comment: Normally, a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/CardLayout.html) is used to accomplish this.  But first, you’ll need to learn to [use layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/).

Comment: You've not told me anything that was not obvious in the original question. Imagine I'm an end-user and you are explaining why/when I might click the checkboxes on the **right-hand side of the GUI.**

Comment: That picture makes no sense to me. What is the point of having two checkboxes without individual labels? How does the use know what each check box represents? This is a poor user interface and needs to be redesigned.

Answer (score -1):

For Java Swing components, you use setVisible(true/false) to show and hide components. Below, I've made some changes to your sample to demonstrate this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f= new JFrame("CheckBox Example");
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setBounds(40,80,200,200);
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setBounds(280, 80, 100, 30);
        rightPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        JPanel rhsCpp= new JPanel();
        rhsCpp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        rhsCpp.add(new JLabel("C++"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        rhsCpp.add(new JCheckBox(""), BorderLayout.WEST);
        rhsCpp.add(new JCheckBox(""), BorderLayout.EAST);
        rightPanel.add(rhsCpp);

        JPanel rhsJava= new JPanel();
        rhsJava.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        rhsJava.add(new JLabel("Java"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        rhsJava.add(new JCheckBox(""), BorderLayout.WEST);
        rhsJava.add(new JCheckBox(""), BorderLayout.EAST);
        rightPanel.add(rhsJava);
        rightPanel.setSize(100, 100);

        final ActionListener checkBoxActionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                JCheckBox checkBoxType = (JCheckBox) actionEvent.getSource();
                if (checkBoxType.getText().equals("C++")) {
                    rhsCpp.setVisible(checkBoxType.isSelected());
                }else {
                    rhsJava.setVisible(checkBoxType.isSelected());
                }
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(f);
            }
        };

        JCheckBox checkbox1 = new JCheckBox("C++", true);
        checkbox1.setBounds(150,100, 50,50);
        JCheckBox checkbox2 = new JCheckBox("Java", true);
        checkbox2.setBounds(150,150, 50,50);
        leftPanel.add(checkbox1);
        leftPanel.add(checkbox2);
        checkbox1.addActionListener(checkBoxActionListener);
        checkbox2.addActionListener(checkBoxActionListener);
        f.add(leftPanel);
        f.add(rightPanel);


        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: GridLayout and BorderLayout is showing error

Comment: You can import them via the following statement: `import java.awt.*;` Next steps for your app might be to make all coordinates dynamic, using such layout managers also for the left hand side and the overall frame. I'd also recommend using an IDE like IntelliJ (free Community Edition) which does many of these things for you automatically.